# Display Firebase data in a Listview without DUPLICATES in it

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

1. While retrieving a COLLECTION from Firebase, I am calling data from one particular field "CATEGORY" as below

   ```
   var catList = (querySnapshot.data.documents[index]["Category"]);
   ```

Sample Data:
[image]

2. I am displaying it in a `ListView` builder horizontally by passing it as an Object to the Text-Widget.
   `child: Text(catList)`,
   It is displaying all fine. just one problem - it contains "duplicates"
3. How to display the data without DUPLICATES?

Comment: Can you please post the concerned code which you use to the build the list view? That would help to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new variable by getting the values from the data in a loop and check for duplicates: (Assuming catList is the variable where the JSON data that you are getting is)

```
var newCatList = {};
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(catList).length; i++) {
  var a = 0;
  if (i = 0) {
    newCatList[0] = catList[0];
  } else {
    for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(newCatList).length; j++) {
      if (newCatList[j]["Category"] == catList[i]["Category"] && newCatList[j]["Sub-Category"] == catList[i]["Sub-Category"] && newCatList[j]["Model"] == catList[i]["Model"] && newCatList[j]["Color"] == catList[i]["Color"] && newCatList[j]["Price"] == catList[i]["Price"]) {
        a = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (a == 0) {
      newCatList[Object.keys(newCatList).length] = catList[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, appreciate you help. I will try the solution